# Var(x) and cov(x, x) don't give the same result in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, covariance, variance

A property of the covariance is, that cov(x, x) = var(x)

However, in numpy I don't get the same result.

```
from numpy import var, cov

x = range(10)
y = var(x)
z = cov(x, x)[0][1]
print y, z
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I obtain the correct result?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must use z=cov(x,bias=1) in order to normalize by N ,because var is also norm by N
(according to [this](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-614d18fe6fcdeb848a222177b2bb5404502bf85f)

Answer (score 12):

The default ddof of `cov` (None) and `var` (0) are different. Try specifying the ddof (or bias):

```
>>> cov(x, x, ddof=0)
array([[ 8.25,  8.25],
       [ 8.25,  8.25]])
>>> var(x)
8.25
```